# C++ overloading constructor problems

Tags: c++, constructor, overloading

I am working on a homework assignment for my C++ class, but I'm have difficulty with my overloading constructor.The default constructor works fine but the overloading constructor will not work properly.Any guidance would be appericated.

```
    /*
Name:Isis Curiel
Date:04/05/2017
Assignment 10
Instructions:
Redo assignment 5 by

1. Defining a class Date that has

(1) Three member variables:

date,
month,
year
(2) member functions

constructor:  Initializes the Date to the given month, day and 
year or to the default value. you can overload the constructor,
or use default arguments.

example use:

Date today(3,31, 2017);  // 03/31/2017

Date firstDay;  // will be 01/01/2017

reset: reset the  month, day and year based on the parameters. So today.reset(4,1,2017); will change today to 04/01/2017.
get_day_of_week: return the day of the week as int 0-6
get_day_of_week_name: return the day of the week as a string
print: print out the date information include the date, month, year, day of the week.
(3) helper funcions:

bool is_leap_year();

// Returns true if the given year is a leap year

int get_century_value();

// Returns a value computed from the century of the year

int get_year_value();

// Returns a value computed based on the years since the beginning of the century.

int get_month_value();

// Returns a value (from a table) for the Date's month

2. write a main function to test the class.
*/

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

class Date {

private:

    int date, month, year, newDate, newMonth, newYear;


    /*
reset: reset the  month, day and year based on the parameters. So today.reset(4,1,2017); will change today to 04/01/2017.
get_day_of_week: return the day of the week as int 0-6
get_day_of_week_name: return the day of the week as a string
print: print out the date information include the date, month, year, day of the week.
     */

public:
    Date() {
        month = 01;
        date = 01;
        year = 2017;
    }
    Date(int fmonth, int fdate, int fyear) {
        fmonth = month;
        fdate = date;
        fyear = year;

    }
    bool is_leap_year(int year) {
        if (((year % 4 == 0) && (!(year % 100 == 0))) || ((year % 400 == 0)))
        {
            ////isLeapYear = true;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    int get_century_value(int year) {

        int centValue;
        year = year / 100;
        year = year % 4;
        year = 3 - year;
        year = year * 2;
        centValue = year;
        return centValue;
    }

    int get_year_value(int year) {

        int y1;
        int yearVal;
        year = year % 100;
        y1 = year / 4;
        yearVal = y1 + year;
        return yearVal;


    }
    int get_month_value(int month, int year) {
        if (month == 1 && is_leap_year(year) == false)
            return 0; ///but doesnt returning 0 cause issues ?
        else if (month == 1 && is_leap_year(year))
            return 6;
        else if (month == 2 && is_leap_year(year) == false)
            return 3;
        else if (month == 2 && is_leap_year(year))
            return 2;
        else if (month == 3)
            return 3;
        else if (month == 4)
            return 6;
        else if (month == 5)
            return 1;
        else if (month == 6)
            return 4;
        else if (month == 7)
            return 6;
        else if (month == 8)
            return 2;
        else if (month == 9)
            return 5;
        else if (month == 10)
            return 0;
        else if (month == 11)
            return 3;
        else if (month == 12)
            return 5;
        else
            return 6;

    }
    int get_day_of_week(int month, int date, int year) {
        int x;
        x = ((date + get_month_value(month, year) + get_year_value(year) + get_century_value(year)) % 7);
        ///((getMonthValue + getYearValue + getCenturyValue)%7)
        return x;

    }

    void get_day_of_week_name(int month, int date, int year) {

        if (month > 12 || month < 1) {
            cout << "Try again Please enter a month, day, and year, separated by " <<
                "spaces(e.g., '7 4 2008') :  ";
            get_day_of_week(month, date, year);
            cin >> month;
            cin >> date;
            cin >> year;

        }
        else if (month == 2 && date == 29 && is_leap_year(year) == false)
        {
            cout << "Try again Please enter a month, day, and year, separated by " <<
                "spaces(e.g., '7 4 2008') :  ";
            get_day_of_week(month, date, year);
            cin >> month;
            cin >> date;
            cin >> year;
        }
        else if (date > 31 || date < 1) {
            cout << "Try again Please enter a month, day, and year, separated by " <<
                "spaces(e.g., '7 4 2008') :  ";
            get_day_of_week(month, date, year);
            cin >> month;
            cin >> date;
            cin >> year;
        }
        else if (month == 4 || month == 7 || month == 9 || month == 11 && date > 30) {
            cout << "Try again Please enter a month, day, and year, separated by " <<
                "spaces(e.g., '7 4 2008') :  ";
            get_day_of_week(month, date, year);
            cin >> month;
            cin >> date;
            cin >> year;
        }
        else {
            string dayW;
            if (get_day_of_week(month, date, year) == 0)
                dayW = "Sunday";
            else if (get_day_of_week(month, date, year) == 1)
                dayW = "Monday";
            else if (get_day_of_week(month, date, year) == 2)
                dayW = "Tuesday";
            else if (get_day_of_week(month, date, year) == 3)
                dayW = "Wednesday";
            else if (get_day_of_week(month, date, year) == 4)
                dayW = "Thursday";
            else if (get_day_of_week(month, date, year) == 5)
                dayW = "Friday";
            else if (get_day_of_week(month, date, year) == 6)
                dayW = "Saturday";
            else
                dayW = "INVALID";
            cout << dayW;
        }
    }
        void print() {
            string dayW;
            if (get_day_of_week(month, date, year) == 0)
                dayW = "Sunday";
            else if (get_day_of_week(month, date, year) == 1)
                dayW = "Monday";
            else if (get_day_of_week(month, date, year) == 2)
                dayW = "Tuesday";
            else if (get_day_of_week(month, date, year) == 3)
                dayW = "Wednesday";
            else if (get_day_of_week(month, date, year) == 4)
                dayW = "Thursday";
            else if (get_day_of_week(month, date, year) == 5)
                dayW = "Friday";
            else if (get_day_of_week(month, date, year) == 6)
                dayW = "Saturday";
            else
                dayW = "INVALID";

            cout << "Today is  " << dayW << " " << month <<
                " " << date << " " << year << endl; //prints out day and full date 
        }
        void reset(int newDate,int newMonth, int  newYear) {

            newDate = date;
            newMonth = month;
            newYear = year;
        }

};



int main()
{
    int i = 3;
    int z = 31;
    int f = 2017;

    Date today(i,z,f);  // 03/31/2017
    today.print();
    Date firstDay; // will be 01/01/2017
    firstDay.print();
    Sleep(50000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. Please define *"will not work properly"* - what exactly happens? Please remove all unnecessary parts of this code and only provide a [mcve]

Comment: `03/31/2017` **don't**. Use the international standard everybody understands: `2017-03-31`

Answer (score 5):

You have the assignments backwards.

```
Date(int fmonth, int fdate, int fyear) {
    fmonth = month;
    fdate = date;
    fyear = year;
}
```

should be

```
Date(int fmonth, int fdate, int fyear) {
    month = fmonth;
    date = fdate;
    year = fyear;
}
```

Comment: Addendum: read up on the [Member Initializer List](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). It can save you time, trouble, and it's the only way to do a coup[le things like initialize a base class that requires constructor arguments.